# Run a python script in terminal

Tags: python, linux, debian, interpreter

I am trying to run in terminal `hello.py` python script:

```
#! usr/bin/env python3  
print("Hello", "World!")
```

On invoking the following in terminal (while being in working directory where `hello.py` is located):

```
$ chmod +x hello.py
$ ./hello.py
```

I am getting:

```
bash: ./hello.py: usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I am not able to go beyond it. I've checked the following in terminal 
(maybe needed in further clarification):

```
_____________________________________________________________________
$ python3
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct  8 2014, 10:45:20) 
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.executable)
/usr/bin/python3
_____________________________________________________________________
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
_____________________________________________________________________
$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
_____________________________________________________________________
```

Thanks for any clarification!

Comment: Debian advise to use absolute path of interpreter like `/usr/bin/python3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite simple, you forgot to give the absolute path.

Use #!/usr/bin/env python3

Comment: This isn't entirely clear.  I think you should say, "you forgot to include the first slash."  At a glance, it looks like the same thing he tried.